# Открытие файлов,ошибка

Tags: c, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод

Дан текстовый файл,переписать в другой файл все строки первого,заменив 1 на 0,и наоборот.
assert выдает ошибку на открытие второго файла,в чем проблема?оба файла существуют.
И правильно ли я написал код?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
char a[300];
int f,i;
char c;
FILE *f1;
FILE *f2;
f1 = fopen("f1.txt", "r"); assert(f1);
f2 = fopen("f2.txt", "w"); assert(f2);
for(i=0;!feof(f1);i++){ 
    fscanf(f1,"%c",&c); 
    
    if(c=='1'){
        c='0';
        fprintf(f2,"%s",c); 
        continue; 
    }  
    if(c=='0'){
        c='1'; 
        printf("test");
        fprintf(f2,"%s",c); 
    }
}

fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Неправильно писали бы в файл. Читаете буквами, пишете строками. И сразу у вас будет ошибка памяти. Проверка на **feof** нужно только после **fscanf**.

Исправил ошибки , у меня всё пишется в файл нормально.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -std=c11 -Os fopen.c -o fopen
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int i;
char c;
FILE *f1;
FILE *f2;
f1 = fopen("f1.txt", "r"); assert(f1);
f2 = fopen("f2.txt", "w"); assert(f2);
for(i=0;1;i++){ 
    int nr = fscanf(f1,"%c",&c); 
    if(nr != 1)
      break;
    if(c=='1'){
        c='0';
        fprintf(f2,"%c",c); 
        continue; 
    }  
    if(c=='0'){
        c='1'; 
        fprintf(f2,"%c",c); 
        continue;
    }
    fprintf(f2,"%c",c); 
}

fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> assert выдает ошибку на открытие второго файла, в чем проблема?

Скорее всего, или уже есть файл с атрибутом ReadOnly, или прав для записи файла не хватает.

Еще у вас несоответствие форматных строк типу:

```
fprintf(f2,"%s",c);
```

Ну, и читать символы с помощью `fscanf` - из пушки по воробьям...

Ну, и я бы делал так:

```
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    FILE * f1 = fopen("f1.txt", "r"); assert(f1);
    FILE * f2 = fopen("f2.txt", "w"); assert(f2);
    while((c = fgetc(f1))!=EOF)
    {
        switch (c)  // Или if (с == '1') с = '0'; else if (с == '0') с = '1';
        {
        case '0': c = '1'; break;
        case '1': c = '0'; break;
        }
        fputc(c,f2);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
}
```